# How do you understand that swapping a pointer as an argument to a function can help you swap values

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3

void sort(char *ptr[N]) {
    char *temp = NULL;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            if (strcmp(ptr[i], ptr[j]) > 0) {
                temp = ptr[i];
                ptr[i] = ptr[j];
                ptr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char str1[50], str2[50], str3[50];
    char *str[3] = { str1, str2, str3 };
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        gets(str[i]);

    sort(str);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        puts(str[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

This code swaps strings around but I really don't understand why swapping pointers can swap values. I really want to understand thoroughly.

Comment: `
ptr[0]  0x000000 "bbc"
ptr[1]  0x000008 "abc"
`
if you swap
`ptr[0] 0x000008 "abc"
 ptr[1]  0x000000 "bbc"
`
and array pointers will point this address on the memory.
`
ptr[0] 0x000008
ptr[1]  0x000000
ptr[2]  0x000016
`

Comment: @Akaqlonist I can understand that addresses are exchanged between ptr in sort, but why is the address in str changed when this function is called

Comment: Initially, str contains the addresses of str1, str2 and str3. Upon comparing the strings pointed to by two consecutive elements of str, the pointers contained in these elements might be swapped. Stupidity is reserved to those not caring about understanding, which is not your case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens in your code

- Your strings `str1, str2, str3` were never moved or swapped at all
- `str` is an array of pointers to those `str1, str2, str3` strings, I assume that you think each element of `str` is a whole string if you're from a different language before.
- But each element of `str` just pointers to the first character of the string and that's how strings in c works, a `char*` is a pointer to the first character of a `char` array
- when you swap elements of `str` all you're doing is, moving the pointers around so they'll point to a different string. and those strings (`str1, str2, str3`) were never moved
- when you print each string, as you iterate through `str` you'll get the pointer to a string in a sorted order (pointers are sorted, the string it points to is always there)